# Fleet integration for Barracuda Firewall logs

Tags: elasticsearch

We have configured Fleet server and added Elastic Agents. Output is configured using Logstash. Agent policy is added which contains system integration, its working fine and sending logs to logstash output.
When we try to add Barracuda Cloudgen Firewall integration, integration gets added but its showing following error.

Documentation suggests that it receives output via Lumberjack protocol. There are lumberjack plugins there for logstash-input-lumberjack and logstash-output-lumberjack . Do we need to install any of this plugin ? or it should be fixed any other way, please guide.

Following are the logs from elastic agent log file for reference:

> "log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-12-08T07:09:38.411Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"coordinator/coordinator.go","file.line":857},"message":"Spawned new component lumberjack-default: input not supported","log":{"source":"elastic-agent"},"component":{"id":"lumberjack-default","state":"FAILED"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-12-08T07:09:38.411Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"coordinator/coordinator.go","file.line":857},"message":"Spawned new unit lumberjack-default-lumberjack-barracuda_cloudgen_firewall-542abf24-7edb-4c28-852a-b3454c5fa5a7: input not supported","log":{"source":"elastic-agent"},"component":{"id":"lumberjack-default","state":"FAILED"},"unit":{"id":"lumberjack-default-lumberjack-barracuda_cloudgen_firewall-542abf24-7edb-4c28-852a-b3454c5fa5a7","type":"input","state":"FAILED"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-12-08T07:09:38.411Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"coordinator/coordinator.go","file.line":857},"message":"Spawned new unit lumberjack-default: input not supported","log":{"source":"elastic-agent"},"component":{"id":"lumberjack-default","state":"FAILED"},"unit":{"id":"lumberjack-default","type":"output","state":"FAILED"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"

Answer (score 0):

As detailed to you on Elastic forum [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/fleet-integration-for-barracauda-firewall-logs/348882), you have to update your elastic agent to version at least 8.7.1